# Using sklearn precision_recall_curve function with different classifiers

Tags: python, scikit-learn, precision, precision-recall

This may be an easy question, but I need help understanding how to use the `precision_recall_curve` function in `sklearn`.

I have a binary dataset and am using three classifiers (`SVM`, `RF`, `LR`) to classify it.

The example in sklearn's documentation shows to use the function like this:

```
y_score = classifier.decision_function(X_test)    
precision_recall_curve(y_test, y_score)
```

In the example, `decision_function` is a built-in function for `SVM` classifiers. However, I don't see a function like that for Random Forest classifiers or Linear Regression.

Can someone help me understand what the `y_score` and decision function really is, and how I can calculate it for any classifier?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the second param description in [documentation of `precision_recall_curve`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_curve.html):

> probas_pred : array, shape = [n_samples]
>
> Estimated **probabilities** or decision function.

When `decision_function()` is not present, you may use `predict_proba()` in its place.

Answer (score 0):

For all the other classifiers that do not have a built in `decision_function`, 
you shall use the `predict_proba` function, that does esentially the same thing.

```
y_score = random_forest.predict_proba()
```